# Tcl/Tk LstBox width in CombBox

Tags: combobox, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I configure the listbox component width in a combobox, so that it will fit to longest entry?
The widget width itself (the entry component) can be short, but I'm looking for a way to configure the listbox component to be wider than the entry...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not without a bit of hacking ;)

You can find the implementation of combobox in `combobox.tcl` (in my case `/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.5/ttk/combobox.tcl`. There you see that if you have a combobox

```
set cb [ttk::combobox .cb -state readonly]
```

and invoke it, it creates the following internal widget structure:

```
$cb.popdown.f.l
```

`popdown` is the toplevel that pops down if you click the combobox, `f` a frame, and `l` the actual listbox which contains your values. To fit the longest entry you need to modify the geometry of the `popdown` toplevel.

We try to do so by binding a resize script to the`ButtonPress` event on the combobox, however, this does not work because by default the bindings are handled in the following order (output of `puts [bindtags $cb]`):

```
.cb TCombobox . all
```

So first the events on the widget (`.cb`) are handled, then the events on the class (`TCombobox`), and then on the toplevel (`.`) and finally the events that are bound to all widgets.
What this means is that when we click the combobox, first our resize script is executed, but then the `popdown` toplevel does exist yet, because it will only be created when handling the class event.

The solution is to switch the event handling order for the widget and class:

```
bindtags $cb [list TCombobox $cb . all]
```

Now it should be working! Below a minimal proof of concept:

```
package require Tk                                                              

wm title . "Combobox Listbox resize"                                            
wm geometry . "150x40"                                                          
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1                                              
set cb [ttk::combobox .cb -width 20 -state readonly]                            
grid $cb -row 1 -column 0 
set cmd "$cb configure -values {abarsdhresntdaenstdsnthret erstihre reshterhstierht}"
$cb configure -postcommand $cmd                                                 
bind $cb <ButtonPress> changeGeomPopdown
bindtags $cb [list TCombobox $cb . all]                                         

proc changeGeomPopdown { } {                                                    
    global cb                                                               
    scan [wm geometry $cb.popdown] "%dx%d+%d+%d" w h x y
    wm geometry $cb.popdown "300x${h}+${x}+${y}"                            
}
```

---

To get the desired width you need to ask for the font of the listbox [1]:

```
$cb.popdown.f.l cget -font
```

Then use the `font measure` command ([2]) on every string to determine the pixels you need to fit all entries. Don't forget to add a bit of padding to for a better look and to make sure the scrollbar doesn't overlap with your text.

**NB: To avoid all kind of nasty stuff please make sure that this internal widget structure is in place before you try to modify it, the implementation of `ttk::combobox` might change and then your program won't work anymore!**

---

[1] http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/listbox.htm#M16
[2] http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/font.htm#M10

Comment: Perhaps a horizontal scroll bar would be simple workaround (even though not as nice as a perfectly sized selection list).